# How is windows' cursor smoothing/acceleration calculated?

Tags: windows, algorithm, cursor, mouse, acceleration

I am trying to program my own cursor in an application, but I find that windows' acceleration and/or smoothing of a cursor is much more easy and precise to use than just moving the custom cursor by raising the input magnitude of the mouse to a power. 
If it's a speed curve that has simply been optimized for this accuracy, is there anywhere I can find this curve, or algorithm, because it would be best to have least noticeable difference in using the custom cursor as opposed to the acceleration normally used in windows?

Comment: This might be helpful: [Pointer Ballistics for Windows XP](http://archive.is/20120907165307/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463319.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, but if those graphs shown in the pictures were exactly the ones used in windows xp, it has likely been reworked before the last versions of windows which makes me unsure about them. I'd maybe imagine more inflection points than shown would be used to make it as smooth as it is currently, though I haven't lately tried windows xp's mouse movement if it has changed since then.

Comment: It seems that users can disable the cursor acceleration feature in Windows: [How to Completely Turn Off Mouse Acceleration in Windows](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1953585/completely-turn-mouse-acceleration-windows.html).  This might make users notice a difference if you program your own cursor.

Comment: my reasoning was that, because of how perfect I find windows' acceleration, if someone actually prefers not using it they could go into a settings menu and disable it.